# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, m2eclipse

I am trying to execute the testNG main class using pom.xml file by using the below command in **Maven Run Configurations**.

```
exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.selenium.controls.TestNGMainClass
```

Here, I am using **Java 8**.

But I got the below error.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building seleniumScriptsRegression 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) @ seleniumScriptsRegression ---
[WARNING] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.selenium.controls.TestNGMainClass
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:270)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.331 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-29T10:59:54+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/32M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project seleniumScriptsRegression: An exception occured while executing the Java class. com.selenium.controls.TestNGMainClass -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Kindly help me to fix the issue.

Comment: Can you provide your pom.xml file for exec-maven-plugin, might be the execution column is different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a Main.java in src/test/java

Add this in your pom.xml

```
 <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
                        <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>run-selenium</id>
                            <phase>integration-test</phase>
                            <goals><goal>java</goal></goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

and run it via :

`mvn clean install` or `mvn exec:java`

Comment: Hi, As I googled, maven is looking at src/main/java. But my java class is in src/test/java. May be that is an issue.

Comment: yes, very likely. The test classpath is not included by default, read this : http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-or-java-change-classpath-scope.html

Comment: I am facing the same issue.

Comment: But as a work around, I tried to move my packages from test directory to main directory, it is working fine..

Comment: can you try execute this without your ide (eclipse)? can you share where you find your main class in the maven target folder?

Comment: When I run via command prompt using "mvn exec:java", it is working fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164138/discussion-between-mohan-kumar-and-user6761124).