# How to fix "Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java" error running a Dataflow template from a VM instance in GCP?

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to execute the Dataflow template named **PubSubToBigQuery.java** at a VM instance (OS: "linux", version: "4.9.0-11-amd64", Distributor: Debian GNU/Linux 9.11 (stretch)) to take input messages from a Pub/Sub subscription and write them in a BigQuery table (without modifying the template for the moment). In order to do this I cloned the [GitHub DataflowTemplates repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates) into my Cloud Shell in the $HOME/opt/ directory. Following the README document I've installed Java 8 and Maven 3:

- **Maven 3.3.9** (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T16:41:47+00:00) Maven home: /opt/maven
  **Java version**: 1.8.0_232, vendor: Oracle Corporation
  Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
  Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
  OS name: "linux", version: "4.9.0-11-amd64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

After building the entire project, this is what I'm trying to execute from the comand line to compile the code:

```
sudo mvn -X compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubSubToBigQuery - 
Dexec.cleanupDaemonThreads=false -Dexec.args=" --project=real-demand -- 
stagingLocation=gs://rd_pubsub/staging --streaming=true"
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
[WARNING]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubSubToBigQuery.java
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:270)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  03:21 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-26T10:47:57Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project google-cloud-teleport-java: An exception occured while executing the Java class. com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubSubToBigQuery.java -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project google-cloud-teleport-java: An exception occured while executing the Java class. com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubSubToBigQuery.java
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occured while executing the Java class. com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubSubToBigQuery.java
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute (ExecJavaMojo.java:339)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubSubToBigQuery.java
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:270)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48495043/failed-to-execute-goal-org-codehaus-mojoexec-maven-plugin1-6-0java) or this discussion [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164138/discussion-between-mohan-kumar-and-user6761124) I've also added this piece of XML in pom.xml:

```
<properties>
<testNgMainClass>defaultMainClass</testNgMainClass>
<args>defaultArgs</args>
</properties>
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.6.0</version>
<configuration>
<classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
<mainClass>${testNgMainClass}</mainClass>
<arguments>${args}</arguments>
</configuration>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>run-selenium</id>
<phase>integration-test</phase>
<goals><goal>java</goal></goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

But it's still not working.

Comment: It is not clear to me whose `Main` class is not being found. It may be part of maven, since the template has no such class. If you add `-X` on the command line can you fine anything in the full debug log? (it is probably too big to post here)

Comment: Thanks Kenn! I updated the post by adding the full debug log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clone, compile and run a Dataflow Template is necessary enable all the necessary APIs in your GCP project:

- Dataflow
- Compute Engine
- Stackdriver Logging
- Cloud Storage
- Cloud Storage JSON
- BigQuery
- PubSub

In order to do that you can click in this helper link:

https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=dataflow,compute_component,logging,storage_component,storage_api,bigquery,pubsub

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are not specifying all the parameters needed to execute the [template](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/bf31b611556ee9938305cfedc3501eb3f954265f/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubSubToBigQuery.java#L113) and as you mentioned, you are not modifying the file.

- inputTopic=projects/${PROJECT_ID}/topics/input-topic-name
- outputTableSpec=${PROJECT_ID}:dataset-id.output-table
- outputDeadletterTable=${PROJECT_ID}:dataset-id.deadletter-table

The command should look like this:

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubSubToBigQuery -Dexec.cleanupDaemonThreads=false \
 -Dexec.args=" --project=PROJECT_ID \
 --stagingLocation=gs://bucket-name/dataflow \
 --streaming=true \
 --inputTopic=projects/PROJECT_ID/topics/input-topic-name \
 --outputTableSpec=PROJECT_ID:dataset-id.deadletter-table \
 --outputDeadletterTable=PROJECT_ID:dataset-id.deadletter-table"
```

On the other hand, I recommend to deploy the template into GCP and execute using the gcloud command, follow the [instructions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubSubToBigQuery.java#L82) given within the PubSubToBigQuery.java file